# Docusign - How specify the connect id in API?

Tags: docusignapi

Hy,

Is it possible to specify the connection where we want to transfer the events envelopes by the config_ig or connect_id ?

Because we have to put it as a parameter in our application for many instances. Each instance as his connection for his own events logs.

Search in the API but not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.
There's no way to transfer events.
The connect configurations are account wide, unless you specify users or groups that you want them to apply to.
If you have 2 configurations, then both of these listeners will get the events etc.
You can use APIs to modify/create/delete Connect configurations, but you cannot transfer events between them.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to only put the connect id for select the configuration i want.
But it's not possible, all the active configuration will receive the events, so i have to active only the configuration i want.
Thank you.